# reference request: Type A crystal proof of Schur-positivity

Tags: reference-request, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

In this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272306/what-techniques-are-there-to-prove-schur-positivity, one of the techniques listed to prove Schur-positivity is called a Type-A crystal proof, which apparently Stembridge characterized.  Does anyone have a link to the relevant Stembridge paper, or to something that can explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that it is *[A local characterization of simply-laced crystals](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2003-355-12/S0002-9947-03-03042-3/S0002-9947-03-03042-3.pdf)* (Trans. Am. Math. Soc. **355**, No. 12, 4807-4823 (2003)).